# i am making a tic tac toe game in c, the wincheck function but in the code below is not working

Tags: c

I am making a tic tac toe game in c, the wincheck function in the code below is not working, if there is a win, the game doesn't stop, it keeps running seems that the wincheck function doesn't make the wincheckvalue 1,but why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
char list[10] = {'0',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};

void displayboard()
{
    printf("\n      |      |    ");
    printf("\n  %c   |  %c   |  %c ",list[7],list[8],list[9]);
    printf("\n      |      |    \n");
    printf("--------------------\n");
    printf("\n      |      |    ");
    printf("\n  %c   |  %c   |  %c ",list[4],list[5],list[6]);
    printf("\n      |      |    \n");
    printf("--------------------\n");
    printf("\n      |      |    ");
    printf("\n  %c   |  %c   |  %c ",list[1],list[2],list[3]);
    printf("\n      |      |    \n");
}

int wincheck(char c)
{
    int returnvalue = 0;
    if (list[1] == list[2] == c && list[2] == list[3] == c)
    {
        returnvalue = 1;
    }
    else if (list[4] == list[5] == c && list[5] == list[6] == c)
        returnvalue = 1;

    else if (list[7] == list[8] == c && list[8] == list[9] == c)
        returnvalue = 1;

    else if (list[1] == list[4] == c && list[4] == list[7] == c)
        returnvalue = 1;

    else if (list[2] == list[5] == c && list[5] == list[8] == c)
        returnvalue = 1;

    else if (list[3] == list[6] == c && list[6] == list[9] == c)
        returnvalue = 1;

    else if (list[1] == list[5] == c && list[5] == list[9] == c)
        returnvalue = 1;

    else if (list[3] == list[5] == c && list[5] == list[7] == c)
        returnvalue = 1;
    return returnvalue;

}


int main()
{
    int wincheckvalue;
    int v = 0;
    int a;
    int b;
    while (true)
    {       
        displayboard();
        printf("Player 1(X) ,Input num: ");
        scanf("%i",&a);
        while (list[a] == '0' || list[a] == 'X' )
        {
            displayboard();
            printf("Invalid move!\n");
            printf("Input num: ");
            scanf("%i",&a);
        }
        list[a] = 'X';
        wincheckvalue = wincheck('X');
        if (wincheckvalue == 1)
        {
            printf("Player 1 has won!!");
            break;
        }
        displayboard();
        printf("Player 2(0) ,Input num: ");
        scanf("%i",&b);
        while (list[b] == 'X' || list[b] == '0')
        {
            displayboard();
            printf("Invalid move!\n");
            printf("Input num: ");
            scanf("%i",&b);
        }
        list[b] = '0';
        displayboard();
        wincheckvalue = wincheck('0');
        if (wincheckvalue == 1)
        {
            printf("Player 2 has won!!");
            break;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Please make it a habit to use the proper zero-based indexes for arrays. Using one-based will make you very lonely.

Comment: try to think of a more generic way to calculate. this methodology is not scalable. think of the number of conditions required for a 3d 4x4x4 game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your comparisons like `list[1] == list[2] == c` are wrong.

That comparison is equal to `(list[1] == list[2]) == c`, which means you compare the true/false (the integers `1` or `0` respectively) result of `list[1] == list[2]` to the value of `c`. This will very likely never be true.

You must split your comparison like `list[1] == c && list[2] == c` etc.